# Pentaquark color structure

Tags: standard-model, quarks, color-charge, pentaquarks

I just heard about [pentaquarks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentaquark). How do you assign color charge to a pentaquark like duuc anti c

Comment: Show your work.

Answer (score 2):

The WP figure is self explanatory, once you recall the intermediate W  here [image]
is colorless.

So, then,
$$
\Lambda^0_b \sim \epsilon _{ijk} b^iu^jd^k \to   \epsilon _{ijk} c^iu^j c^k~~s^l\bar c^l \to  ( \epsilon _{ijk} c^iu^j c^k~~u^l\bar c^l) ~ (s^m\bar u^m). 
$$
Follow the color. Now, *within* $P_c^+$, the various quarks may exchange color via gluons, and so you get the same εδ connecting rearrangements of the quarks allowed by the generalized Pauli principle.

Comment: Great! Thank you

Comment: If you accepted the answer, you could click on the checkmark...